# How does one derive the Lorentz transform for rectangular hyperbolas?

Tags: rotations, hyperbolic-functions, special-relativity

I've only seen derivations of the [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) using hyperbola like $x^2-y^2=-1$ as opposed to hyperbola like $y=1/x.$ I've been trying to derive the Lorentz transform for rectangular hyperbolas in the plane, using $H_s=\begin{bmatrix}   e^s&0\\   0&e^{-s}   \end{bmatrix},$ where $s$ is the [Rapidity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity) The rectangular hyperbola spacetime diagram is basically a $45$ degree rotation clockwise of the standard diagram as shown below.

How does one derive the Lorentz transform for rectangular hyperbolas? And why does no one derive it this way?

[image]

Comment: If you know it in the other coordinate system, just apply a basis transformation with the $45^\circ$ rotation matrix.

Comment: I only want to derive it with rectangular hyperbolas